# Why LinkedList and arraylist extends AbstractList in java?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist, linked-list

Why `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` in *Java*?

Abstract classes are used when we want to specify a common behaviour in implementation classes.

But all the methods which are in `AbstractList` are overridden by `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

So what is the use of extending this class?

Comment: [The top level description of the class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) seems sufficient to me.  Since `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` have different backings, I would expect them to implement certain methods differently.

Comment: LinkedList does extends AbstractList in Java (1.6). It extends AbstractSequentialList

Comment: Abstraction is not just extending common behavior. It is also to establish relationship between closely related classes. Read up more on [Abstraction](http://techieme.in/techieme/using-abstract-classes-and-interfaces/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`subList(int,int)` method is not overriden by both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, and for this `AbstractList` provides a common implementation

From Java source

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return (this instanceof RandomAccess ?
                new RandomAccessSubList<E>(this, fromIndex, toIndex) :
                new SubList<E>(this, fromIndex, toIndex));
    }
```

In addition there are other methods which are not overriden like `toString()` and `iterator()`

Comment: So just for this only single method , they are extending it?

Comment: @Raj Don't forget `containsAll` and `toString` from `AbstractCollection` (and `LinkedList` doesn't implement `removeAll` or `retainAll` either).

Answer (score 5):

You can get Answer from Here,,, [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)

This class provides a skeletal implementation of the List interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface backed by a "random access" data store (such as an array). For sequential access data (such as a linked list), AbstractSequentialList should be used in preference to this Class.
To implement an unmodifiable List, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the get(int index) and size() methods.

To implement a modifiable List, the programmer must additionally override the set(int index, Object element) method (which otherwise throws an UnsupportedOperationException. If the List is variable-size the programmer must additionally override the add(int index, Object element) and remove(int index) methods.

The programmer should generally provide a void (no argument) and Collection constructor, as per the recommendation in the Collection interface specification.

Unlike the other abstract Collection implementations, the programmer does not have to provide an Iterator implementation; the iterator and listIterator are implemented by this class, on top the "random access" methods: get(int index), set(int index, Object element), set(int index, Object element), add(int index, Object element) and remove(int index).

The documentation for each non-abstract methods in this class describes its implementation in detail. Each of these methods may be overridden if the Collection being implemented admits a more efficient implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Not all methods from `AbstractList` are overridden. Remember that `AbstractList` subclasses `AbstractCollection`, which defines methods like `containsAll` or `toString` which are not overridden by either `ArrayList` nor `LinkedList`.

Comment: Is there is any collection which mostly uses implemenation of abstractlist

Comment: Sure, I'd say that `Collections.singletonList` returns an implementation that defers most everything to `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 1):

Usage is noted at the top of the AbstractList source file

"This class provides a skeletal implementation of the {@link List}
 interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface
 backed by a "random access" data store (such as an array).  For sequential
 access data (such as a linked list), {@link AbstractSequentialList} should
 be used in preference to this class."

So essentially it provides some methods to build around and a framework that is more robust than the List interface.